# Jquery send data within function param

Tags: php, jquery

I have this issue with my jquery code:

```
<?php

//I oppen a text document, read the text inside of it and write it inside my html page.
//When someone clicks on a line, I want to take that very same line and send it via  select(String) function. 
$handle = fopen($_POST['lien'], 'r');

if ($handle)
{       
    while (!feof($handle))
    {       
          $buffer = fgets($handle);     
          echo "<div onclick='select(\" ".$buffer." \");'>".$buffer."</div><br/>";
             //It works when I put a simple string within the select param: 
             //echo "<div onclick='select(\" text \");'>".$buffer."</div><br/>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

The jquery code :

```
function select(text){
        alert(text);
        //$("#selected").html();
    }
```

where do you guys think is the problem ?

Thanks :)

Comment: where is your jQuery code?

Comment: it's very simple code so far :

function select(text){
  alert(text);  
 }

Comment: It's pretty obvious that you need to post the jQuery code if you want any help

Comment: Sorry my baad, I pasted it.

Comment: I've just noticed something, with the last line of my document it works, it appears inside the alert, but I want each one to be shown when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change line:

```
    echo "<div onclick='select(\" ".$buffer." \");'>".$buffer."</div><br/>";
```

to

```
    echo "<div onclick='select(\" ".rtrim($buffer)." \");'>".$buffer."</div><br/>";
```

or to:

```
    echo "<div onclick='select($(this).text());'>".$buffer."</div><br/>";
```

Comment: Thanks, It works with rtrim(), but still can't understand what was the problem? Whey rtrim() is necessary?

Comment: `fgets` read lines from file and return them with end of line symbols, that symbols prints to you html code and cause JavaScript error - SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (I see it in Firefox JavaScript console). Error raising because end of line in JavaScript works similar as ; symbol - end of statement, so, in you code statement ends before string literal was closed

Comment: And keep in mind comments of @Roman Hocke about double quotes and other symbols - you better use variants with `json_encode()` or with `select($(this).text());`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Your $buffer contains some double-quotes, which then interfere with surrounding double-quotes. Look at produced HTML code if this is the case, maybe You'll see something like this:

```
<div onclick='select("He said: "Freeze!"")'>
```

... which Javascript can't parse correctly. If this is the case, consider using:

```
echo "<div onclick='select(".json_encode($buffer).")'>";
```

Comment: It's not only problem of double-quotes, but many other characters may cause the same problem - probably newline-characters and similar. This is probably the reason, why rtrim() mentioned in another answer helped (You probably had \n at the end of $buffer).